# Edit Java Application's Memory from C#

Tags: java, c#, memory, reverse-engineering, editing

**Is it possible to edit a java application running in javaw.exe with the .NET framework? If so, could you use the MemorySharp libraries?**

I've been asked to automate text into a Java application. I primarily code in .NET and would prefer development in Visual Studio. However, if it must be developed in Java, that would also be okay. I will need to trace back multi-level pointers.

Comment: When you say 'automate text into a Java application' do you mean drive the app as if a user were typing something from the keyboard?

Comment: @stephendnicholas I would prefer text was entered programmatically rather than simulated keystrokes. I'm also looking to read from addresses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversing multilevel pointers found in the process space of a .NET/JVM based program is generally a bad idea. The pointers are too volatile.

Cheat Engine has some features for manipulating Java programs by locating the location of Java objects in memory without pointer traversal.

See: http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=576927&sid=5bfd402b090c4872a602a3202b619d9d

This forum post isn't a complete example but it should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Java is very good at reading strings entered as command line arguments to javaw.exe.  You would likely want to tap into the highly ubiquitous "public void main(String[] args)" method.

Java is also very good at reading files and extracting strings that it finds therein, as well as reading URLs, and retrieving strings from a database.  There are a large number of ways that data can be passed into a Java application.

You might also consider the use of a 'webservice' which would allow a .NET based app (for example) to make a 'webcall' to a Java based webservice and pass it information (traditionally in JSON or XML formats).  This has been found to be a good way in interrelate two programs written in different languages so that they work effectively together.

Good luck, and please show us what you have tried so that we can help you make your example work.